# Where Factory class should be placed on in a MVC application?

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns, factory

I'm learning MVC pattern and building a simple java application without any framework, just building the package structure by myself in order to understand and practice the MVC concepts.
I have the packages: model, view and controller so far.
So, I have a Factory class to build some objects (part of the model) and I'm not sure in which of these packages place the factory class.
I'm sure is not part of view :), so should it be part of model or controller? Or may be is it correct to have other package to place it?

Comment: Looks like you answered it yourself. "So, I have a Factory class to build some objects (part of the model)". Put it under the model package.

Comment: Instead of factories, I'd suggest to use a _dependency injection container_. As for the entities, e.g. the domain objects, you can directly create them by using the _new_ operator.